# how to create a table with a concatenated array

Tags: javascript, html-table, stringify

Currently i have a btn which calls a function as follows:

```
function ingredientsList()  {
    const allIngredients = [].concat(...ingredientsResults.map(obj => obj.ingredients))
    
    allIngredients.reduce((acc, item) => {
        acc[item] = (acc[item] || 0) + 1
        return (document.getElementById("resultsDiv").innerText = acc)
    },{})
};
```

this gets information from a bunch of arrays as follows:

```
const ingredientsResults = [
    {
        dinnerName: "Vegetable Soup",
        ingredients: ["potatoes", "onion", "spring onion", "lentils", "beans", "turnip" ]
    },
    {
        dinnerName: "Spaghetti",
        ingredients: ["spaghetti pasta", "tomato box","tomato box", "onion", "sundried tomatoes", "tomato paste", "lentils"]
    },
    {
        dinnerName: "Fiskebolle",
        ingredients: ["box of fiskebolle", "box of fiskebolle", "potatoes", "brocolli", "carrots"]
    }
];
```

when the button is clicked it returns [Object, object] back to the "resultsDiv".I have researched how to put this either in a list / table with the concatinated results but the only thing i find is JSON.stringify() and that gives me a bunch of nonsense! Is there a reason for this or am i missing something? i primarily want to display the results in a table / list

my desired results are something as follows:

```
{potatoes: 2, onion: 2, spring onion: 1, lentils: 2, beans: 1, …}
beans: 1
box of fiskebolle: 2
brocolli: 1
carrots: 1
lentils: 2
onion: 2
potatoes: 2
spaghetti pasta: 1
spring onion: 1
sundried tomatoes: 1
tomato box: 2
tomato paste: 1
turnip: 1
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The function that your button calls doesn't make sense, specifically `return (document.getElementById("resultsDiv").innerText = acc)`  It looks like you are trying to count duplicate ingredients.  What is the intention and what output do you expect?

Comment: my intention is to get a output witha list of items and there duplicates so for example onions: 2 etc..

Comment: It would be helpful if you model your expected output in the question.

Comment: Would the return you want for example be the name of the ingredients in the first column and the quantity in the second?

Comment: yeah that is basically what im trying to acheive :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something you can do is after creating the object with the name of the ingredient and the quantity, it is creating a new loop going through all the objects and creating the `tr` and `td`

```js
const ingredientsResults = [
    {
        dinnerName: "Vegetable Soup",
        ingredients: ["potatoes", "onion", "spring onion", "lentils", "beans", "turnip" ]
    },
    {
        dinnerName: "Spaghetti",
        ingredients: ["spaghetti pasta", "tomato box","tomato box", "onion", "sundried tomatoes", "tomato paste", "lentils"]
    },
    {
        dinnerName: "Fiskebolle",
        ingredients: ["box of fiskebolle", "box of fiskebolle", "potatoes", "brocolli", "carrots"]
    }
];


function ingredientsList()  {
    const allIngredients = [].concat(...ingredientsResults.map(obj => obj.ingredients))
    
    const result = allIngredients.reduce((acc, item) => {
        acc[item] = (acc[item] || 0) + 1
        return acc // change this
    },{})
    // add this
    const table = document.querySelector('#myTable')
    
    Object.keys(result).forEach(dname => {
      const tr = document.createElement('tr')
      const td1 = document.createElement('td')
      const td2 = document.createElement('td')
      
      td1.innerText = dname
      td2.innerText = result[dname]
      
      tr.append(td1)
      tr.append(td2)
      
      table.append(tr)
    })
    
    // end
};

ingredientsList()
```

```html
<table id="myTable">

</table>
```